# PXFormula not updating

Tags: acumatica

I've created a new custom bound field `UsrMatchCode` for the BAccount DAC. My goal is to create a field which I can query from a web service call to identify "potential" duplicate customer records. My plan is to concatenate the following into a single 9-character calculated field:

- First 5 Characters of Address.PostalCode
- First 2 Characters of Address.AddressLine1
- First 2 Characters of Contact.FullName

But before I can get this far, I'm stuck getting the value of the PXFormula to display when updating/saving existing records. Strangely, it does output a value for new records. *See screenshot.*

[image]

I've reduced the PXFormula to using constants only to rule out other fields causing the problem.

```
public class BAccountExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount>
{
    private class index1 : Constant<int>
    {
        public index1() : base(0) { }
    }
    private class length5 : Constant<int>
    {
        public length5() : base(5) { }
    }
    private class testString : Constant<string>
    {
        public testString() : base("123456789") { }
    }

    #region UsrMatchCode
    public abstract class usrMatchCode : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(9)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Match Code", Enabled = false)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Substring<testString, index1, length5>))]
    public virtual string UsrMatchCode { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid using PXFormula and PXDBxxx types at the same time.

The PXDBxxx attribute tells the framework you want to persist the field value to DB and reload it's value from DB while PXFormula tells the framework the string value needs to be computed from the formula. The two approach appear incompatible because it's not clear cut whether the value will be coming from DB or from formula after the record has been persisted to DB. Other attributes like PXDefault are more suited for PXDBxxx types because it will only run at initialisation.

I would recommend either to use PXFormula with the unbound PXString type or to use PXDefault instead of PXFormula for initialisation of PXDBString.